# Makefile:1: *** missing separator. (I use tab, not spaces)

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, ubuntu-20.04

I know this question have been asked a lot of times, but I can't fix my error anyway.

I'm doing a Makefile with this content:

```sh
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/" ]; then
        mkdir -p $HOME/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/ 
fi
```

When I run it, I get

```
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

In order to check if the script has spaces instead of tab, I type on the prompt

```
cat -t Makefile
```

so I get

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/" ]; then
^Imkdir -p $HOME/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/
fi
```

What's the problem?

Comment: That appears to be a shell script, not a Makefile. See e.g. the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Simple-Makefile) for information about what a Makefile should look like.

Comment: Thanks, I will read some documentation for a better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `make` is not `bash`, it has its own syntax. Your code would be like this:

```makefile
ifeq ($(wildcard $(HOME)/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/),)
  MKDIR_OUTPUT:=$(shell mkdir -p $(HOME)/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/)
endif
```

No tabs needed here since it is not a recipe.

Comment: Thanks! I'm learning bash and it is my first Makefile. I was wrong about using same syntax. Now I see I don't need a Makefile for my purpose.